# CucumberJs : is it possible to define more than one "World"

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs

Following [this example](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/nodejs_example.md), I have written 2 different tests.

Is it possible to define more than one "World" ? i.e. define different World for different tests suite ?

For me for the moment, it seems not to be possible, because all files are read and executed, and only last `setWorldConstructor()` call is taken in account...

Thanks,

Xavier

Answer (score 2):

I had the same requirement. You can not have multiple world instances.
Take a look at an issue I raised asking for some additional functionality. In there I outlined some current workarounds and some future features. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/1174